# Problem when I try pass a struct pointer to a function

Tags: c, pointers, struct

Whats's wrong with this code?

```
typedef struct jogador{
    char nome[7];
    int pecas[6][2];
}Jogador;

void distribuir_pecas( Jogador* jogadores );

int main()
{
    Jogador* jogadores;
    jogadores = (Jogador*) malloc( 4 * sizeof(Jogador));
    distribuir_pecas( jogadores );
    return 0;
}
void distribuir_pecas( Jogador* jogadores ){
    int domino[28][2];
    int vetor_aux[28];

    int i, j;
    int peca_sorteada;
    int num_jogador = 0;
    int num_domino = 0;
    srand(time(NULL));

    for( i = 0; i < 28; i++){
        vetor_aux[i] = 1;
    }
    for( i = 0 ; i < 7; i++){
        for( j = 0; j < 7; j++){
            if( j == 0 ){
                j = i;
            }
            domino[num_domino][0] = i;
            domino[num_domino][1] = j;
            //printf("%d*%d\n", domino[num_domino][0], domino[num_domino][1]);
            num_domino++;
        }
    }

    while( num_jogador < 4 ){
        for( i = 0; i < 6; ){
            peca_sorteada = rand()%28;
            if( vetor_aux[peca_sorteada] ){

                vetor_aux[peca_sorteada] = 0;
                jogadores[num_jogador].pecas[i][0] = domino[peca_sorteada][0];
                jogadores[num_jogador].pecas[i][1] = domino[peca_sorteada][1];
                i++;
                printf("[%d|%d]\n",jogadores[num_jogador].pecas[i]                        [0],jogadores[num_jogador].pecas[i][1]);
            }
        }
        printf("\n\n");
        num_jogador++;
    }
}
```

When I try equate `domino[peca_sorteada][0]` to `jogadores[num_jogador].pecas[i][0]`, for exemple, using a `->` operand a compilation error ocurrs, but with `.` operand the printf don't print the correct value. Why????

Comment: Please clarify your question.  Give an example of some code that doesn't work, and give the output it produces.  Also, please simplify your code example (do we really need to see all these loops, and the mallocs, etc.?)

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this is the underlying problem, but this:

```
int domino[28][2];
....
for( i = 0 ; i < 7; i++){
    for( j = 0; j < 7; j++){
        if( j == 0 ){
            j = i;
        }
        domino[num_domino][0] = i;
        domino[num_domino][1] = j;
        //printf("%d*%d\n", domino[num_domino][0], domino[num_domino][1]);
        num_domino++;
    }
}
```

is going to cause you problems. `num_domino` will be 49 by the end of this double loop, but the `domino` array is only 28 elements long.

Comment: You *do* use it inside the loop, though. And you're writing to elements of `domino` that are outside its bounds.

Comment: It´s true Cameron. I'm increase 'i' before print the content of 'jogadores'.Thanks!